# Add mark-up after/before link in wp_list_categories

Tags: jquery

This is probably a trivia question, but I can't seem to find a simple solution.

This is my wp_list_caterories php...

```
<?php wp_list_categories(array(
    'orderby'   => 'name',
    'show_count'    => 1,
    'title_li'  => ''
)); ?>
```

This currently outputs this...

```
<li class="cat-item cat-item-1"><a href="http://example.com/category/uncategorized/" title="View all posts filed under Uncategorized">Uncategorized</a> (8)
</li>
```

I am trying to add this `<span>&#124;</span>` before my link so the final output looks like this...

```
<li class="cat-item cat-item-1"><span>&#124;</span><a href="http://example.com/category/uncategorized/" title="View all posts filed under Uncategorized">Uncategorized</a> (8)
</li>
```

Is it possible to do this within the PHP. I could do it using jquery but I'd rather use the PHP.

Many thanks for any help.

Josh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one possibility - add a filter to functions.php of your theme:

```
add_filter ( 'wp_list_categories', 'span_before_link_list_categories' );

function span_before_link_list_categories( $list ) {
$list = str_replace('<a href=','<span>&#124;</span><a href=',$list);
return $list;
}
```

Comment: This worked great thanks. Just out of interest. If I got wp_list_categories twice on the page, how do you target this function to a specific wp_list_categories. Again thank you!!!

Comment: unfortunately, that is not really possible. if you have access to one the `wp_list_categories()` codes, you could add the filter just before the code and remove it after the code.